# jQuery: how to add eventListener to whole document/Webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add an eventListener to whole document with jQuery?

```
$("document").click(function (){        
  $("h1").css('color', 'red');
})
```

I want the h1 to change color if clicked anywhere in the document/webpage. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just using "body" in quotation marks as following also works.

```
$("body").click(function (){ 
  $("h1").css('color', 'red');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the double quotations in the `$("document")` line

```js
$(document).click(function (){ 
  $("h1").css('color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello</h1>
```